# Display a list of all Google Drive files on Google site

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sites, drive

I am trying to display this as a web app. It only returns 1 file on the site. The logs show 50+ files. Why doesn't htmloutput show all the files like the logs do. Any help would be awesome.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var query = 'fullText contains "Printers"' ;
  var folders, pageToken;
  do {
    folders = Drive.Files.list({
      q: query,
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });

    if (folders.items && folders.items.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length; i++) {
        var folder = folders.items[i];

        Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', folder.title, folder.id);
      }
    } else {
    }
    var Output3 = folder.id; 
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Output3);
    pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  return output
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `for` loop iterates, it's overwriting the previous contents.

```
var Output3 = folder.id;
```

You would need to use something like:

```
var Output3 = "";//define this outside the `for` loop
Output3 = Output3 + folder.id;
```

Here is a rework of your full code:

```
function doGet() {
  var query = 'fullText contains "Printers"' ;
  var folders, folder, pageToken, foldersLngth = 0, theItems, output="";

  do {
    folders = Drive.Files.list({
    q: query,
    maxResults: 100,
    pageToken: pageToken
  });

  foldersLngth = folders.items.length;
  theItems = folders.items;

  if (theItems && foldersLngth > 0) {

    for (var i=0; i < foldersLngth; i++) {
      folder = folders.items[i];
      Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', folder.title, folder.id);
      output = output + folder.title + ", " + folder.id;
    };
  };

  //var Output3 = folder.id; 
  //HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(Output3);
  pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);
};
```

Comment: Awesome. It Works. Thank you for your help